# deleting multiple characters from text file using C

Tags: c, string, file

I am trying to delete specific strings from the text file. I've to delete two strings from the file [Ipsum, printing]. I tried first deleting only first string from the file. But the string can not be deleted. I am unable to correct my code, where I am making mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
  int main() {
    int j = 0, i;
    char getText[1000] = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry";
    FILE * fptr, * fp2;
    char a[1000], temp[1000];

    char key[50] = "Ipsum", textDelete_2[50] = "printing";

    fptr = fopen("D:\\test.txt", "w");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
      printf("File can not be opened. \n");
      exit(0);
    }

    fputs(getText, fptr);

    fp2 = fopen("D:\\temp.txt", "w");
    if (fp2 == NULL) {
      printf("File fp2 can not be opened. \n");
      exit(0);
    }
    printf("\n processing ... \n");

    while (fgets(a,1000,fptr)) {
      for (i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (a[i] == ' ') {
          temp[j] = 0;
          if (strcmp(temp, key) != 0) {
            fputs(temp, fp2);
          }
          j = 0;

          fputs(" ", fp2);
        } else {
          temp[j++] = a[i];
        }
      }

      if (strcmp(temp, key) != 0) {
        fputs(temp, fp2);
      }
      fputs("\n", fp2);
      a[0] = 0;
    }

    fclose(fptr);
    fclose(fp2);
    printf("\n processing completed");
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: `strstr()` and `memmove()` are your friends. (but copying into a new string will work as well)

Comment: `"w"` --> `"w+"`. and Do `fflush` and `rewind`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your input file is open with the argument `w` that stands for `write`,so it will clean the content of the input file making the input useless .

Also your code generates symbols if before the end of the line or before the end of 1000 chars readed are \0 (if you didnt write an entire line or 1000 chars it will read the rest of the content as symbols).

Final code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
  int main() {
    int j = 0, i;
    FILE * fptr, * fp2;
    char a[1024], temp[1024];

    char *key = "THIS", *textDelete_2 = "IS";

    fptr = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
      printf("File can not be opened. \n");
      exit(0);
    }

    fp2 = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
    if (fp2 == NULL) {
      printf("File fp2 can not be opened. \n");
      exit(0);
    }
    printf("\n processing ... \n");

    while (fgets(a, sizeof(a), fptr)) {
      for (i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
          if (a[i] == 0)break;
        if (a[i] == ' ') {
          temp[j] = 0;
          if (strcmp(temp, key) != 0) {
            fputs(temp, fp2);
          }
          j = 0;

          fputs(" ", fp2);
        } else {
          temp[j++] = a[i];
        }
      }

      for (i = 0; i < strlen(temp); i++){

          if (!isalpha(temp[i]))temp[i] = ' ';
      }
      if (strcmp(temp, key) != 0) {
        fputs(temp, fp2);
      }
      fputs("\n", fp2);
      a[0] = 0;
    }

    fclose(fptr);
    fclose(fp2);
    printf("\n processing completed");
    getchar();
    return 0;
  }
```

Input:

```
THIS IS SPARTAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Output:

```
 IS SPARTAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: It worked for one string but how can I delete multiple strings from the sentence. Like I've to delete THIS and IS. I tried to modify your code, but can't the correct result. Please help!!!

Comment: @nischalinn Put the while loop in a function that request the argument "a" and then call it twice.("a" is the string that is deleted)